# Simulate security log in windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I use a program that reads the security log on a windows 2008 and looks for who has logged into the domain ( i have setup active directory services/Ldap on windows 2008).
To simulate multiple users logging in, I want to be able to use a tool and possibly put it inside a batch script and automate it. Is there any tool that can help me simulate generation of the Log-on/Log-off into a box ? I looked around and found an utility called auth.exe but it does not seem to generate security logs

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet probably would be creating a virtual environment with a Server 2008 DC and a client (or maybe a handful) where you script logins (either through the network or interactively by using AutoAdminLogon regkeys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a bunch of

```
"net use /d \\server    
"net use \\server"
```

statements into a BAT script (that runs on another machine of course) ought to do it. You need to ensure that you have auditing turned on - do normal logins create security events?